# Получение списка Flngerprint'ов android

Tags: android, безопасность

Появилась необходимость узнавать "был ли добавлен новый отпечаток пальца на устройство". Реализовать я это решил при помощи `KeyGenerator`'а при помощи которого мы получаем `SecretKey`, затем просто шифруем `cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key)`.

В итоге каждый раз когда будет происходить добавление отпечатка пальца на телефон - будет возникать необходимость генерировать новый `SecretKey` ибо старый не будет подходить и мы будем получать `InvalidKeyException` тем самым мы узнаем что список отпечатков пальцев был изменен.

Вот только проблема, `SecretKey` нельзя никак сохранить, метод `hashCode` всегда возвращает одно и тоже вне зависимости от экземпляра, сами поля имеют одно и тоже состояние тоже вне зависимости от экзмпляра...как его можно сохранить чтобы потом в дальнейшем была возможность шифровать(и как следствие определить, был ли изменен список отпечатков пальцев или нет)? Возможно есть какие-то другие способы узнать о состоянии отпечатков пальцев?

Comment: Мне понравился ваш вопрос, я правда не работал с этим, но мб вам стоит переопределить hashcode добавив свой параметр?

Comment: @ГеоргийЧеботарев hashCode является методом класса который реализует  SecretKey, его не переопределить, в моем случае это AndroidKeyStoreSecretKey(реализация SecretKey которую предоставляет метод generateKey из KeyGenerator) - от является hide и к нему нельзя даже получить доступ

Comment: Если вы не можете переопределить hascode(), но он все-время возвращается одинаковый код, напиши свой собственный статический метод, получающий на вход объект с SecretKey и возвращающий свой hash. Если объекты отличаются только в скрытых полях, к которым у вас нет доступа - то у вас проблема. Ибо нельзя идентифицировать объект, если внешни он идентичен свои собратьям.

Comment: Именно, объекты идентичны вне зависимости от того когда были получены(до смены отпечатков пальцев либо после), но при этом при попытке шифрования эти SecretKey'и оказываются разными, в случае с одним может вылететь InvalidKeyException а в случае с другим будет всё ок

Comment: в таком случае, боюсь ничего не вйдет. реализация намерено закрыта, а значит если вы сможете сохранить отпечаток - вы обойдете их систему безопасности. Поищите либы или готовые решения на английской части stackoverflow, мб там кто-то уже поднимал похожий вопрос.

Comment: @ГеоргийЧеботарев в том и дело, я понимаю что нельзя получить список именно отвечатков, необходимо узнать был ли он изменен...думал получить какой-то хэш/состояние или хоть что-то похожее на это. Дело в том что есть приложения которые уже имею в себе эту реализацию, надеюсь они обошлись без использования NDK)